# Measuring divergence in a way other than using the dot product of Nabla (∇)operator?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

How will you measure divergence in a way other than using the dot product of Nabla (∇)operator?
For example, here I have another way of finding the gradient (normal) without using the Nabla (∇) operator.

**Objective**:To find the gradient (normal) for $x^2 + y^2 -8$ at (2,2)

**The usual method is below:-**
Grad($x^2 + y^2 -8$)= ∇($x^2 + y^2 -8$)=2xi+2yj -> normal
Therefore, the gradient at (2,2) is obtained by substituting in the above ‘normal’. 
Gradient is 4i+4j-> vector1

**Here is another method:-**

dy/dx=-x/y

dy/dx(2,2)=-1

We know that the product of slope of normal and slope of tangent is -1.
So, the slope of normal here is 1.

The vector for line with slope ‘m’ is i+mj

Our required vector is i+(1)j  = i+j -> vector2

See, vector1= vector2 **(I have obtained normal (gradient) without using nabla operator).**

*Can anyone provide a different (intuitive) way of measuring curl and divergence? Maybe, something like take a infinitesimally small circle and integrate all the radial components to find the curl.*

[Here the notations are clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsUOe.png)

Comment: MathJaX formatting would be greatly helpful here, for readability.

Comment: A suggested reading is the directional derivative. This defines the relationship between vectors and gradients.